# Why do so many wikis use version control systems such as Git to store their data?

Tags: database, version-control, wiki

What are the advantages and disadvantages of doing this, relative to using a database?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software

Answer (score 2):

IMO, a version control system (VCS) like Git allows the administrators of a wiki to easily revert any changes, mistakes, misinformation that may be introduced to the content. They are fast and, in the case of Git, don't rely on only one single centralized repository to contain the content. Git is a distributed system, meaning all copies of a checked-out repository are complete and identical to the repo it was checked out from. This allows any copy of the repo to be restored or updated from most any one of the other distributed copies (this may or may not be relevant to wiki admins/designers/creators - ?).

However, with the development of very fast key-value databases and document databases (Redis, Couch, Mongo, etc) it certainly is reasonable to wonder why wikis use VCS, and why they stick with relational databases like MySQL and Postgres (FYI: there is a new wiki, Wiki.js taking advantage of JavaScript and MongoDB).